# relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol linking error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am programming an exercice for my university in C++ and it compiles correctly, but when I link the `.o` files to get my executable, my console shows this error.

> /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: Estudiant.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `_ZTI12PRO2Excepcio' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `recompile con -fPIC` just do it. Add the `-fPIC` option for your `.so` libraries and you should be fine.

Comment: Please provide the errors messages in english next time, by executing with `LANG=C` before your command, e.g. `LANG=C make`

Comment: Just changed the language ;). So, can you explain deeply how to recompile with -fPIC? Sorry I'm a begginer in this.